# Recommendations on creating a GUI for an XML configuration file

Tags: xml, user-interface

I want to create a Windows GUI to allow the user friendly editing of a configuration that is stored in XML. The XML uses nested elements, typically with attributes for configuration values, in a conventional way. Designing and creating a GUI (probably in C# using a tree control to show the overall structure and a PropertyGrid to edit specific properties) would be a reasonable amount of work. It also seems wrong, to me, to create a completely bespoke application when the problem could be solved much more generally with the XML schema and some additional 'metadata'.

Is anyone aware of any frameworks or libraries (open source ideally, but I would consider commercial at the right price) that would provide a basis for an 'XML configuration file' GUI application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We decided to go the 'C# application with tree control to show overall structure and PropertyGrid to edit specific properties' route in the end. It was less work than we'd anticipated - once the basic application structure was there, we simply added classes for each of the objects that we wanted to be configurable. Each class exposes properties that can be edited by the PropertyGrid, and is responsible for reading/writing its properties to XML in the appropriate format. There may have been easier ways, but this gave us plenty of control without being too time-consuming.

We found the following resources useful during development:

- Ordering items in a property grid - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6611/Ordering-Items-in-the-Property-Grid
- Controlling the description area height - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31497/Gain-Control-Over-PropertyGrid-s-Description-Area
- Solid-dragging splitter - [Refresh the panels of a SplitContainer as the splitter moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521731/refresh-the-panels-of-a-splitcontainer-as-the-splitter-moves)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use XForms, which is available in a number of free and a number of commercial applications (the sets are not disjoint).  You might start by looking at XSLTForms, Orbeon, BettterForms, and EMC Formula.

Comment: XSLTForms is described at "XForms to XHTML+Javascript (AJAX) conversion based on a unique XSL transformation." I'm looking to build a Windows application here, so unless I'm missing something I don't think this is directly relevant.

I don't know XForms well enough to know whether it could help, but past experiences with non-Windows-native GUIs haven't been entirely positive.

Comment: XSLTForms runs in the browser, so it does run under Windows.  If you want an application that will run *only* on Windows, of course, XForms is the wrong target.

Comment: Windows only is the target platform, yes.

Comment: It's your application, of course, but your response does make me curious; why would it be important that your app be Windows *only*?  Why would an app (or the technology underlying it) be less useful or interesting because it can run on more than one platform?

Comment: Fair question. It's not important that it's Windows only, but the requirement is only for Windows and (without wishing to prejudge XForms and family, with which I have no experience) I have seen cross-platform Windowing toolkits produce inferior applications to those produced 'natively'.