# Update win form display while resizing a splitView control?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

Default behaviour on a Windows Form when moving the split view divider shows a 'shadow' of the divider and updates the display after having moved it. Is there a way to force the display to update continually while dragging/resizing?

Comment: `Invalidate()` when you resize it and drag it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can't edit comments so deleted previous one. I've tried using Invalidate() and Update() in various events for the split control: mouseMove, mouseDown, splitterMoving. All produce no changes. The movingSplitter event does fire correctly but calling Invalidate, update nor refresh force any redraw. Any idea why?

Comment: Ah. It is redrawing, but just not with the new splitter position. I guess I'll have to manually set the splitter position unless there's an automatic way that I'm unfamiliar with?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking to constantly update the display of a windows form while dragging a splitter, there's an answer here: [Refresh the panels of a SplitContainer as the splitter moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521731/refresh-the-panels-of-a-splitcontainer-as-the-splitter-moves)

### A bit of info for anyone interested

The splitView control has some events that would appear to be useful in this situation particularly the splitterMoving event.

Calling Refresh(), Invalidate() and/or Update() in this event does redraw the control (or the whole form?), but only as it is. The splitter hasn't really moved when it's in the 'shadow dragging' state. So it's simply updating constantly with the same information and so appears to be doing nothing.

The splitterMoving event does have access to a variables splitX and splitY which contain the new values for the splitter as it's moving in the 'shadow state'. These values are used once the dragging is finished to set the splitterDistance.

However using these values to directly update the splitterDistance var and call a Refresh() result in some odd behaviour to the splitter, seemingly as it's got it's own internal logic to handle moving the splitter and setting manual values during this cause interference.

The answer posted at the top of this post ([Refresh the panels of a SplitContainer as the splitter moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521731/refresh-the-panels-of-a-splitcontainer-as-the-splitter-moves)) overcomes this by turning off the built-in movement and then directly setting the splitterDistance. It uses multiple events and setting states on the splitter and works very well, with a caveat.

### CPU Usage

Updating the form every tick while dragging caused my 6th Gen i5 3.3ghz cpu to go from almost 0% usage to 25%+ just while moving the splitter. As I envision my form being used while multitasking I thought that the effort and CPU usage were not going to be worthwhile for a simple visual enhancement.