# SplitContainer visual updates glitchy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, splitcontainer

I have a large splitcontainer with many elements inside. I recently implemented [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521731/refresh-the-panels-of-a-splitcontainer-as-the-splitter-moves) to refresh the visuals while resizing.

It works fantastic. It does the job. However, it's super glitchy and doesn't look good.
[See example here](https://youtu.be/5aTxj8Kdu8s)

What could I potentially pursue to eliminate the graphical glitches? I want the resizing to be smooth and without elements flashing and jittering.

Comment: Is this _in_ Visual Studio (as your question and tags indicate)? Or, did you write this as an app using a UI framework like WinForms or WPF or something else? If you are getting this in WinForms, you may want to carefully manage invalidating regions during mouse moves. Have you set double buffering to _true_?

Comment: @Flydog57 I'm building my app using WinForms, in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The [solution in this thread](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/728551/Remove-flickering-due-to-TableLayoutPanel-Panel-in) solved it for me. The fix was to doublebuffer everything.

Moving the splitter is now smooth and no flickering.

Comment: Your answer is helpful! You can mark it so that it can help more people